# pgRouting stopped working after database backup

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, pgrouting

I have these two tables in postgresql , PATHWAY , and the vertices table that i created using pgr_createTopology, called PATHWAY_VERTICES_PGR. Everything was great until i decided to backup the database to restore it later, now that i have restored it, with the same postgres 9.3.4 x64, postgis 2.1.3 and pgrouting 2.0 versions, nothing has changed but the fact that i have restored it, and now the pgr_dijkstra stopped working, im receiving this error every time i query for pgr_dijkstra:

```
ERRO:  Error computing path: Unknown exception caught!
********** Error **********
ERRO: Error computing path: Unknown exception caught!
SQL state: 38001
```

but when i search for the error code:

```
38001   containing_sql_not_permitted
```

An example of query that was completely fine until the restore:

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost, geom FROM pgr_dijkstra( ' SELECT r.gid as id, r.source, r.target, st_length(r.geom) as cost,r.geom FROM PATHWAY r' ,956358,734134, false, false ) as di JOIN PATHWAY pt ON di.id2 = pt.gid
```

I've already tried reinstalling Postgres, deleting and adding the postgis and pgrouting extensions again but the error persists. If you guys have any idea let me know, these postgresql error codes are hard to decipher

Comment: The message: "ERRO: Error computing path: Unknown exception caught!" means something in the C++ code blew up. Is this the same hardware as before? More or less memory? had the postgresql.conf file changed? Does ANY pgr_dijkstra() query work? You have huge node ids, this can be a problem because it needs a HUGE amount of memory. You might try renumbering your nodes and see if that work.

Comment: same hardware as before, same OS, 32GB or ram, i also had the entire data folder backup up just in case so all conf files are exactly the same, most shortest path queries i put other filters to reduce memory usage.
I'll make a new couple of tables (edges + vertices_pgr) with 100k records to test if this is a memory problem.
Also testing with another shortest path methods available, bdDijkstra and A*

Comment: please see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112739/pgrouting-pgr-dijkstra-function-error

for a detailed technical answer on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a memory allocation problem.

Your source and target nodes have high id's and PgRouting tries to allocate the memory based on the highest node id it can find, even if there is only a few edges and nodes in the graph.

Dijkstra, drivingDistance and other functions have the same problem.
IMHO this is a real problem since you can't select a subgraph from a huge graph without renumbering the edges and nodes, which renders unusable the query parameters of these functions.

A simple test case to reproduce the problem : Create a small graph with 1 edge and starting and ending nodes id of 2 000 000 000 and 2 000 000 001. You ll get an error running dijkstra on these two nodes.

Technical analysis follows :

Looking at the C source code (PgRouting v2.0.0), in src\bd_dijkstra\src :

```
bdsp.c
```

... 
line 271 : computing max node id

```
  for(z=0; z<total_tuples; z++) {
    if(edges[z].source<v_min_id) v_min_id=edges[z].source;
    if(edges[z].source>v_max_id) v_max_id=edges[z].source;
    if(edges[z].target<v_min_id) v_min_id=edges[z].target;
    if(edges[z].target>v_max_id) v_max_id=edges[z].target;
```

then line 315, the v_max_id is used as parameter...

```
  ret = bidirsp_wrapper(edges, total_271tuples, v_max_id + 2, start_vertex, end_vertex,
                       directed, has_reverse_cost,
                       path, path_count, &err_msg);
```

in BiDirDijkstra.cpp
...
line 281, v_max_id + 2 = maxNode

```
int BiDirDijkstra::bidir_dijkstra(edge_t *edges, unsigned int edge_count, int maxNode, int start_vertex, int end_vertex,
                path_element_t **path, int *path_count, char **err_msg)
{
    max_node_id = maxNode;
    max_edge_id = -1;

    // Allocate memory for local storage like cost and parent holder
    DBG("calling initall(maxNode=%d)\n", maxNode);
    initall(maxNode);
```

and then line 67, trying to allocate A LOT of memory :

```
void BiDirDijkstra::initall(int maxNode)
{
    int i;
    m_vecPath.clear();
    DBG("BiDirDijkstra::initall: allocating m_pFParent, m_pRParent maxNode: %d\n", maxNode+1);
    m_pFParent = new PARENT_PATH[maxNode + 1];
    m_pRParent = new PARENT_PATH[maxNode + 1];
    DBG("BiDirDijkstra::initall: allocated m_pFParent, m_pRParent\n");

    DBG("BiDirDijkstra::initall: allocating m_pFCost, m_pRCost maxNode: %d\n", maxNode+1);
    m_pFCost = new double[maxNode + 1];
    m_pRCost = new double[maxNode + 1];
...
```

Indirectly related to http://pgrouting.974090.n3.nabble.com/pgrouting-dev-PGR-2-Add-some-robustness-to-the-boost-wrappers-td4025087.html

Comment: I dont know if this specific problem was fixed in pgsql 9.4 but, after upgrading both server and database files to the newer version, the problems vanished, querying like butter right now, no allocation problems whatsoever.

Thank you for your input it saved me a lot of time :)